# setState through two for loops

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to setState for an array of objects that one of its keys/properties is an array through two for loops.

I have been trying several solutions (none of them worked for me) below is one of them. if i move  `var secondArr = [];` inside the loop the entire files of all users go to every user

```
state = {
    users: [
        index: "",
        firstName: "",
        files: [],

    ];
}

handleDate = async () => {
    var firstArr = [];
    var secondArr = [];
    //firstCount means the user number in the database
    for (var i = 0; i < firstCount; i++) {
        // i get some result from a call called file
        //secondCount means the number of files for each user in the database
        for (var j = 0; j < secondCount; j++) {
            // i get some result from called file  
       //this also can be secondArr.push({index:result[0], files:file})
            secondArr.push(file);    < ------------- I guess the problem is here, the right files needs to be save in the array of the right user
        }
        // i get an array as a result from a call called result
        firstArr.push({ index: result[0], firstName: result[1], files: secondArr });

        this.setState({ users: firstArr });
    }

}
```

Comment: Check your `state=` code, it isn't valid JavaScript right now. Also you're setting the state inside the loop, which means you have multiple asynchronous calls to `this.setState` all happening more or less at the same time, all overwriting the `users` field. What you need to do is first compose the entire Object, then set `users`, *once*.

Comment: I understand could you provide a solution with some code that may solve the problem ?

Comment: Where is all this happening? In the constructor or some lifecycle method? I think some of your code is missing (at least I am not able to follow)

Comment: @dubes This is a separate function that gets the data regarding the users from database (blockchain)

Comment: Can you provide the model of the data you are trying to loop through? I think there is even a simpler solution than how you are trying to solve it. As well take @ChrisG advise, Its bad to call setState all those times as it will bring about many rerenders which might have performance implications unless you are to cater for that in shouldComponentUpdate

Comment: @FUN_ As far as I can see, all you have to do is move the `this.setState()` call down, below the subsequent `}`. If you do that, `firstArr` will be fully filled, then be saved to `state`, once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes that I can see, which can lead to a behaviour you are not expecting.

First, you should declare the *inner* array variable inside the first loop, else you may keep adding files across multiple users. This may or may not be your intention.

Secondly, you are calling `setState` in a loop, this will not work as you expect because:

1. `setState` calls are actually batched by react. They will not fire
   immediately.
2. You are mutating the state, from 2nd setState call on
   wards, you are changing the **same** array. React may decide not to
   re-render 2nd call onwards, as it sees the same array. I will update
   this answer with resources about immutability later.

With my suggested changes, your code should look like:

```
handleDate = async()=>{
    var firstArr=[];

    for (var i = 0; i < firstCount; i++) {
        // i get some result from a call called file
        var secondArr=[];
        for (var j = 0; j < secondCount; j++) {
            // i get some result from called file  
            secondArr.push(file); 
        }
       // i get an array as a result from a call called result
       firstArr.push({index:result[0], firstName:result[1], files:secondArr});

    }
    this.setState({users:firstArr});
}
```

Comment: The same files[] go to every users instead of the right files, how to setState outside the loop

Comment: still facing the problems with my solution? both the points should be addressed in the code I shared, if you put the right Files in the 2nd Array, it should be unique for each entry in firstArr. `setState` is already moved outside the loop, see it is called after the 1st loop has ended.

Comment: @FUN_ var secondArr = []; inside the loop the entire files of all users go to every user --> could be a problem with how you are getting the "files". Can you please create a small replica of your problem in https://codesandbox.io/ ? perhaps with just 3 users

Comment: Thanks for you effort